Composition of one-sided continuous functions
Almost every calculus textbook states a theorem about the composition of continuous functions being continuous. But it seems difficult to state similar theorems about one-sided continuity because of what seems to me a lack of standard notation.
For instance, if $f$ is continuous from the right at $x=c$ and $g$ is continuous from the right at $f(c)$, then I think we cannot generally conclude anything about $g(f(x))$. But if it is know that the way $f(x)$ approaches $f(c)$ as $x \to c^+$ is such that it only attains values to the right of $f(c)$ (at least for $x$ in some neighborhood to the right of $c$), then we can conclude the composition $g(f(x))$ is right continuous.
I feel like this would be pretty simple to describe in a clear way if there was a notation like
$\lim_{x \to c^+} f(x) = l^+$
or something. Is there some standard notation for this behavior (maybe the one above)? If so, I am interested in identifying some texts that use it.
